# How can I find the record from a data set that is most similar to a test record, that is stored in another data frame?

Tags: r

I have two data frames, similar to the structure below. I want to find the row from the first data frame that would be closest in values to the one single record in my second data frame. So in this case I would expect the row with team A as my result.

```
Team    Var1    Var2    Var3
A       4       5       6 
B       10      10      10
C       15      14      18


Team    Var1    Var2    Var3
D       5       5       4
```

I thought I could use kNN with k=1 to solve the problem? As essentially I'm trying to find the record with the lowest dissimilarity. I'm not sure if this is the right approach?

Columns 9 to 46 in my data are numeric. Hence I have just extracted them to get train & test

```
data_train <- train[,c(9:46)]
data_test <- test[,c(9:46)]
```

Column 2 is the name of the team as shown earlier

```
data_train_target <- train[,c(2)]

similar <- knn(train = data_train, test = data_test, cl = data_train_target, k=1)
```

However, I do not get the expected output i.e. A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `dist()` function, which calculates the Euclidean distance.

assume the following dataframes as you mentioned above:

```r
> df1 <- data.frame(Team = c("A","B","C"),Var1=c(4,10,15),Var2=c(5,10,14),Var3=c(6,10,18))
> df1
  Team Var1 Var2 Var3
1    A    4    5    6
2    B   10   10   10
3    C   15   14   18

> df2 <- data.frame(Team = "D",Var1=5,Var2=5,Var3=4)
> df2
  Team Var1 Var2 Var3
1    D    5    5    4
```

We can combine the 2 dataframes into a single matrix, with the row to match as the first row:

```r
> m <- rbind(df2,df1)
> m
  Team Var1 Var2 Var3
1    D    5    5    4
2    A    4    5    6
3    B   10   10   10
4    C   15   14   18
```

Next we use `dist()` to calculate the Euclidean distance for each combination of rows, knowing the row we wish to find the smallest distance to is row 1.

```r
> dm <- dist(m)
Warning message:
In dist(m) : NAs introduced by coercion
> dm
          1         2         3
2  2.581989                    
3 10.708252 10.132456          
4 22.420229 21.478672 11.832160
```

In order to find which row is closest to row 1 we can use `which.min()` on the first column. First we have to convert the dm object to a matrix.

```r
> dm <- as.matrix(dm)
> dm
          1         2        3        4
1  0.000000  2.581989 10.70825 22.42023
2  2.581989  0.000000 10.13246 21.47867
3 10.708252 10.132456  0.00000 11.83216
4 22.420229 21.478672 11.83216  0.00000
```

We see that as a matrix the distance values are duplicated to fill the upper triangle, and a distance is also calculated from each row to itself (the diagonal). To find the row with the smallest distance to 1, we look at the first column of this matrix and eliminate the first row (which is the distance from row 1 to itself).

```r
> dm[-1,1]
        2         3         4 
 2.581989 10.708252 22.420229
```

We can call `which.min()` on this result to identify the row closest to row 1.

```r
> which.min(dm[1,-1])
2 
1
```

The returned value here appears a bit odd when printed. The "2" refers to the name of the list element, because it was row 2 of our combined matrix (from `cbind(df2,df1)`), but the actual value returned by the function is "1", which is the closest row from df1.

All of these steps could be combined into one call with:

```r
> which.min(as.matrix(dist(rbind(df2,df1)))[1,-1])
2 
1
```

You alluded to KNN in your OP. This code is similar to what a KNN model would do, finding the closest neighbors as measured by some distance in N-dimensional space (3 dimensional in your case).

Answer (score 2):

I think a cautionary iterative approach is fine, but using `dist` by itself will result in way more calculations than needed. (By `rbind`ing one frame with another, you are getting distances between all rows within the first ... when you just need distances between rows in the first and rows in the second.)

I propose a function that provides the closest row in one frame using rows from another.

```r
closest <- function(y, x) {
  inds <- outer(seq_len(nrow(x)), seq_len(nrow(y)), function(a, b) {
    rowSums(abs(x[a,] - y[b,])^2)
  })
  apply(inds, 2, which.min)
}
```

Using your two frames as starting points (I'll augment the second one just for the sake of vectorization and completeness):

```r
x1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Team    Var1    Var2    Var3
A       4       5       6 
B       10      10      10
C       15      14      18")

x2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Team    Var1    Var2    Var3
D       5       5       4
E       15       5       4
F       15       55       4
G       15       55       24")
```

Find for `x2` the closest row from among `x1`:

```r
closest(x2[,-1], x1[,-1])
# [1] 1 2 3 3
```

From here, it should be relatively trivial to extend to whatever uses you have. For instance, to *instead* return the closest row:

```r
closest2 <- function(y, x) {
  inds <- outer(seq_len(nrow(x)), seq_len(nrow(y)), function(a, b) {
    rowSums(abs(x[a,] - y[b,])^2)
  })
  x[apply(inds, 2, which.min),,drop = FALSE]
}
closest2(x2[,-1], x1[,-1])
#     Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1      4    5    6
# 2     10   10   10
# 3     15   14   18
# 3.1   15   14   18
```

I ordered the variables the way I did so that it would work well in a `%>%` pipeline, as in:

```r
x %>%
  do_something(.) %>%
  closest2(., some_reference_frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need any machine learning technique for this. Wouldn't simple mathematics suffice ?

Let's assume the two dataframe you have is `df1` and `df2`. As you mentioned `df2` has only one record so we can subtract that value from each of the rows in `df1`, take absolute value and find the row with minimum difference which will give you row 1 from `df1`.

```
df1[which.min(rowSums(abs(df1[-1] - df2[rep(1, nrow(df1)), -1]))), ]

#  Team Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    A    4    5    6
```

---

Lets break it down to understand step-by-step

Repeat rows in `df2` so that it is of same length as `df1`

```
df2[rep(1, nrow(df1)), -1]
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
#1      5    5    4
#1.1    5    5    4
#1.2    5    5    4
```

Subtract `df2` from `df1`

```
df1[-1] - df2[rep(1, nrow(df1)), -1]
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1   -1    0    2
#2    5    5    6
#3   10    9   14
```

Take absolute value of the dataframe and use `rowSums` to calculate the absolute difference in each row in `df1` from `df2`

```
rowSums(abs(df1[-1] - df2[rep(1, nrow(df1)), -1]))
#[1]  3 16 33
```

Select the row with minimum difference using `which.min`

```
which.min(rowSums(abs(df1[-1] - df2[rep(1, nrow(df1)), -1])))
#[1] 1
```

Finally, subset that row from `df1`

```
df1[which.min(rowSums(abs(df1[-1] - df2[rep(1, nrow(df1)), -1]))), ]
#  Team Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    A    4    5    6
```

---

As mentioned by @r2evans if there are more number of rows in `df2` and you want to find the closest row in `df1` for each row in `df2` we can use `lapply` to loop over each row index and get a list of closest rows.

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(i) 
    df1[which.min(rowSums(abs(df1[-1] - df2[rep(i, nrow(df1)), -1]))), ])
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Team = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), Var1 = c(4L, 10L, 15L), Var2 = c(5L, 10L, 
14L), Var3 = c(6L, 10L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Team = structure(1L, .Label = "D", class = "factor"), 
Var1 = 5L, Var2 = 5L, Var3 = 4L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))
```

Comment: If the second frame is not 1 row, this might be a good use of `sapply` on the indices of the smaller frame, to compare with the whole first frame.

Comment: Thanks Ronak and @r2evans. I realized I needed to use the FNN library. Works perfectly now.